# Is it possible to ping a host and get a delay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ping

Developing an app that uses data synchronization. Sending images (even resized) takes time if it's done over slow internet connection. Thinking, it would be best first to check internet speed, and sent data only if the speed is acceptable. There's Apple Reachability class but it only has method for checking wifi is on. I guess for me, it would be enough to ping a host and grab delay information out of the ping cmd result. That delay info I would use for deciding is it worth to send data now or to wait.

Comment: Latency != bandwidth, sure that ping is what you really need? Although, if it is, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437643/ios-ping-with-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability or ping won't tell you how fast or slow the file will be transmitted. That is a function of ping_time + (file_size / bandwidth). For any large file, the ping_time is much smaller than file_size/bandwidth.

The easiest way to measure this is for the app to download and upload a not-too-small-not-too-large file and decide if in fact the upload and download speeds are "fast enough".

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is fairly involved, however Apple has a complete working example program here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS. `- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet sequenceNumber:(uint16_t)sequenceNumber` never gets called, even after adding `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>` to Info.plist.