# iPhone Socket Streams and valid IP Addresses

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, networking, tcp

I'm trying to create a pretty basic TCP/IP Server and Client (which will be the iPhone) setup. I've been using the Apple example code as shown here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html

I got my read and write streams working well. I'm connecting to a local network via WiFI using IP addresses.

However I'm now having trouble checking if the IP address can be found and crucially if it can  connect to the server. I looked at Reachabilty example Apple provide but it still reports a success, even if I type in a random non existant IP like: 123.456.7.8

Can anyone guide me on what I should be looking at? Is what I done correct for what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the server? Can you use Bonjour? This would make things simple.

Answer (score 0):

The reachability framework only tells if a packet can be routed, not if it will go anywhere.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html.

If you want to see if you can get to a network address, you should check reachability, and then ping it: [iOS - Ping with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437643/ios-ping-with-timeout).  In all my iOS apps, I don't bother to check the ping.  I know I'm using good web addresses, and I think reachability is enough.

Note Bene: Reachability is a bear.  You have to start it in a background thread.  Do not run it from your foreground thread, it can take forever to comeback, and kill your app.