# iOS timeout of ping and ttl

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, timeout, ping

I want make ping with timeout and TTL. I use code by Apple (["Simple Ping"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html)). I read it 
["iOS ping with timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437643/ios-ping-with-timeout). I change code:

```
CFSocketNativeHandle sock = CFSocketGetNative(self->_socket);
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec  = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 100000; // 0.1 sec
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (void *)&tv, sizeof(tv));

bytesSent = sendto(
    sock,
    [packet bytes],
    [packet length], 
    0, 
    (struct sockaddr *) [self.hostAddress bytes], 
    (socklen_t) [self.hostAddress length]
);
```

But I don't understand where I should put code that will show me timeout of receiving packets. Also I need to make ping with TTL (time-to-live) information. I want get information based on this pattern: `icmp_seq=count from=ip_address ttl=value_of_ttl time=value_of_replytime_ms`

Answer (score 0):

To modify the default TTL in the IP Header, call setsockopt with IP_TTL as parameter (tested with IPv4):

```js
- (BOOL)setTTL:(int)ttl{
    CFSocketNativeHandle sock = CFSocketGetNative(self->_socket);
    int status  = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
    if(status < 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The  ["iOS ping with timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437643/ios-ping-with-timeout) example add a output timeout to the socket. From what I understand, it will timeout if the packet is not been sent by the socket within this period. I could be wrong, but I cannot find this "timeout" value from the ICMP header and IPv4 header ([ICMP Packet format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)). 
Here are the console log and request, response packet captured using apple's simple ping:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you only want to know the response time of the ping, I guess you can track it yourself in the delegate methods. Get timestamps when "didSendPacket" and "didReceivePingResponsePacket" functions called and then compare the difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can always put some limit time on the receivefrom:

```
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 10000;
        setsockopt(recv_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct   timeval));
```