# Swift: SimplePing timer not firing

Tags: swift, ping

I am trying to use this solution, [iOS SimplePing delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506428/ios-simpleping-delegates),  to create a timeout for my SimplePing implementation but it is not working. There is nothing built into the SimplePing library to accomplish this.

I have tried inputting the timer in `@objc func sendping()` and `public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16)` because I have tracked its progress to those points but it is never actually fired in any of these functions.

```swift
    public func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
        pingTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
```

And

```swift
    @objc func sendPing() {
        self.pinger!.send(with: nil)
        pingTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
```

This is timerFired()

```swift
    @objc func timerFired () {
        pingResponse = String(format: "Response = DID NOT RECIEVE LATENCY")
        print(pingResponse)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your chosen API you are responsible to schedule the timer on the runloop (what you didn't).

The *self-scheduling* API is

```
pingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFired), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Or use the more contemporary closure based API

```
pingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] timer in
    self?.pingResponse = String(format: "Response = DID NOT RECIEVE LATENCY")
    print(self?.pingResponse)
}
```